# With a template how to use {{attribute}} with one 'record' compared to #each using a find() cursor?

Tags: meteor

I know using a Template you can display multiple documents with their attributes like:

```
// html
<template name="hello">
{{#each greetings}}
   {{message}}
{{/each}}
</template>

// js
Template.hello.greetings = function() {
   return Greetings.find();
}
```

Which shows Greeting.message for each greeting found document.

My question is how to use this template for only one document? (incl. no available document)

From javascript side I would use something like `return Greetings.findOne({'id' : Session.get("greeting_id")});`

But when using the template:

```
<template name="hello">
   {{message}}
</template>
```

an error is thrown: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined

## UPDATE

For now I use this on JS side, using the template as suggested by @tom-wijsman below:

```
Template.hello.greeting = function() {
   var greeting = Greetings.findOne({'id' : Session.get("greeting_id")})
   if (greeting)
       return greeting;
   return {message: ""};
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Handlebars.js also has a [#with helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html).

```html
<template name="hello">
    {{#with greeting}}
        {{message}}
    {{/with greeting}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.hello.greeting = function() {
    return Greetings.findOne({'id' : Session.get("greeting_id")});
}
```

Comment: _Bedankt_  //  Yes I figured this just out myself. The remaining problem to overcome is when the template is rendered when findOne returns {}. I fixed this with returning {greeting:''} in this case, see my update in the question.

Comment: @MichelLöhr: If you want to short hand that you could do `return greeting ? greeting : { message: "" };` but you probably want to check whether there is actually a greeting, perhaps `{{#if greeting}}{{/if greeting}}` around it as an alternative might work; I haven't tried it, but it might...